# removal of svg object after transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a set of paths that fade away after a user clicks on the item. I do this with a transition and opacity

```
let t0 = paths.transition().duration(2000).attrTween("d", arcTween)
    .style("opacity", function(d) {return (d.class == "root") ? 0.0 : 1.0})
    .on("end", function(d) {
            this._current = d;
    })
```

After the object fades away and the transition completes how can I go about removing the path from the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use selection.remove();

As a transition exists for each item in a selection, the end function triggers at the end of each transition, so you can use d3.select(this).remove() at the end of the transition to remove the path/element being transitioned:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",500)
  .attr("height",300);
  
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
  
var squares = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(d3.range(20))
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("y", function(d,i) { return Math.floor(i/5) * 40 + 10 })
  .attr("x", function(d,i) { return i%5 * 40 + 10; })
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 30)
  .attr("fill",color)
  .on("click",transition);
  
  
function transition() {
  d3.select(this).transition()
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10)
    .on("end", function() {
      d3.select(this).remove();
    })
    .duration(1000);
    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add on to what Andrew did above .remove() is always called at the end of the transition [Bostock's General Update Pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234). So an alternative transition function could be:

```
function transition() {
  d3.select(this).transition()
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10)
    .duration(1000)
    .remove();   
}
```